# Gem from github in a different directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi im a bit astonished,

why sometimes a gem (installed with bundle install) isn't stored in the `Project/vendor` folder, but instead in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bundler/gems` folder.

This issues that, assets from this gem are not getting precompiled.

Is there a decent ways for handling  this.

Comment: Run `bundle env` which will tell you where the path configuration is set. See what `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` are set to.

Comment: Okay, i get  `GEM_HOME ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484`
`GEM_PATH ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484:~.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle install --path specify_path_that_you_want`

so it will always install all of your gems in that your specified directory.